# SpirePDF MAUI PdfDocument Display

Tags: c#, .net-maui

I have been working on getting a PDF Viewer working in Net MAUI. In Xamarin, I displayed a PDF in Webview. Not a problem. In MAUI, you don't do that. I installed SpirePDF(free) and have it loading the PDF from file. When adding it to VerticalStackLayout (which will be the Content for a ScrollView), it fails on conversion to IView. Any ideas or suggestions?
   `VerticalStackLayout vsl = new VerticalStackLayout(); PdfDocument viewPdf = new PdfDocument(); Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("CommanderGrady.Resources.Images.adventure218.pdf"); viewPdf.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\leuol\source\repos\CommanderGrady\CommanderGrady\Resources\Images\adventure218.pdf"); vsl.Add((IView)viewPdf); return vsl; }`

Comment: I have checked the class `PdfDocument` and found it implements the IDisposable and ICloneable interface. So it can't be converted to the IView.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is either wait for Maui to catch up or design in Xamarin.

Comment: But you can open the pdf file in a browser.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Please explain. That was my first thought but intellicode indicated an error with assigning that to src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a sample and the pdf can show in the browser. So you can try the following code.

```
string fullpath = xxx; // provide the file path
await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
    {
        File = new ReadOnlyFile(fullpath)
    });
```